# Сделать реферальную ссылку в виде субдомена

Tags: .htaccess

На сайте есть реф программа с ссылкой типа `www.site.ru/ref=login`.

Сейчас задача сделать ссылку типа `www.login.site.ru`, и что-бы login через htaccess перенаправляло на `/index.php?ref=login` но ссылка оставалась с поддоменом.

Собственно все понятно, но, что же нужно прописать в .htaccess, что-бы логин юзера на месте поддомена сайта не выбивал ошибку и отправлял этот логин get'ом в index.php ?

Нашел вот такую статейку (не реклама) [Клик](http://searchengines.guru/showthread.php?t=618353), тут в принципе все как мне нужно, но пример рассчитан на 1 папку bbs, а мне нужно вытаскивать имя поддомена в файл get'ом и сверять с базой.

Comment: Предлагать оплату за задачи здесь не принято. Сайт для других целей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подойдет?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)\.site\.ru$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.ru/ref=%1
```

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, Вам нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^www\.(.+)\.site.ru$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ref=$1 [NC,L]
```